# Changing many variables to datetime in Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with around 1 million rows and I'd like to convert 12 columns to datetime. Currently they are "object" type. I previously read that I could do this with:

```
data.iloc[:,7:19] = data.iloc[:,7:19].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
```

This does work, but the performance is extremely poor. Someone else mentioned performance could be sped up by doing:

```
def lookup(s):
"""
This is an extremely fast approach to datetime parsing.
For large data, the same dates are often repeated. Rather than
re-parse these, we store all unique dates, parse them, and
use a lookup to convert all dates.
"""
dates = {date:pd.to_datetime(date) for date in s.unique()}
return s.apply(lambda v: dates[v])
```

However, I'm not sure how to apply this code to my data (I'm a beginner). Does anyone know how to speed up changing many columns to datetime using this code or any other method? Thanks!

Comment: For large dataframes, using the parse_dates argument while reading CSV, pd.read_csv(parse_dates=True) works better

Comment: Do all your dates have the same format?

Comment: Yes, all dates are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If all your dates have the same format you can define a dateparse function, then pass it as an argument when you import.  Furst you import datetime, then use datetime.strf (#define your format here).

Once that function is defined, in pandas you set the parse dates option to True, then you have an option to call a date parser.  you would put date parser=yourfunction.

I would look up the pandas api to get specific syntax